# Meaning of Ceramic Capacitor markings

Tags: capacitor, symbol, ceramic

[image]I was inspecting a PCB with a magnifying glass and noticed some of the light brown ceramic smd capacitors have 3 digit markings on them. Is there a "standard" of what these markings stand for? The first digit looks like a K with a line above it (K̄), and the other two digits are always a letter followed by a number. Example: K̄J4 or K̄A5

Comment: Can you upload a picture?

Comment: Can you add a clear, in focus photograph of them?

Comment: Probably manufactuerer dependent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you didn't even google search. Before asking a question - try googling it. You'll be surprised at what you can find with 5 seconds to spare.

I googled K̄A5 and the first link is a Kemet PDF. 
http://www.kemet.com/Lists/ProductCatalog/Attachments/735/KEM_C1095_MIL-PRF-32535.pdf

Searching the document with again, the K̄A5, I find the following on page 12.

[image]

Comment: When I posted this I thought it was an R instead of a K. Once I found a better magnifying glass and edited my post. I did find this same page then. My apologies.

Comment: @jAce no need to apologize!

Answer (score 1):

See page 12 of [this](http://www.kemet.com/Lists/ProductCatalog/Attachments/735/KEM_C1095_MIL-PRF-32535.pdf) datasheet. In summary

> KEMET MIL-PRF-32535 ceramic capacitors will be marked in accordance
> with the military specification on case sizes ≥ 0805. Case sizes below
> 0805 will not be marked. Two sides of the ceramic body will be laser
> marked with a “K̄” to identify KEMET, followed by two characters to
> identify the capacitance value.
>
> The marking appears in legible contrast. Illustrated below is an
> example of an MLCC with laser the marking of “K̄A5”, which designates
> a KEMET device with the rated capacitance of 100 nF

Answer (score 1):

There are two common SMD marking schemes: three digit (e.g. `104`) and letter+digit (e.g. `A5`). The last digit encodes the exponent, and the two first digits, or a single letter, encode the mantissa in picofarads. Two digits encoding is pretty straigthforward (they represent a number between 10 and 99), and the letter encoding is usually done according to [the following table](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/chipcap.htm):

```
A   1.0     J   2.2     S   4.7     a   2.5
B   1.1     K   2.4     T   5.1     b   3.5
C   1.2     L   2.7     U   5.6     d   4.0
D   1.3     M   3.0     V   6.2     e   4.5
E   1.5     N   3.3     W   6.8     f   5.0
F   1.6     P   3.6     X   7.5     m   6.0
G   1.8     Q   3.9     Y   8.2     n   7.0
H   2.0     R   4.3     Z   9.1     t   8.0
                                    y   9.0
```

For example,

```
"104" -> 10 * 10^4 = 100000pF = 100nF
"A5" -> 1.0 * 10^5 = 100000pF = 100nF
```

Of course, there are different encodings out there, so check the datasheet from the manufacturer or measure the actual value to be sure.